# Using Capybara syntax correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I have an assignment where I'm trying to have a webpage generate a list of owners and their dogs. Specifically, I'm trying to list the first_name of the owner and their respective dog_name on the page. Now my tests have worked so far with a single owner/pet pair but when I try to test the page with pre-generated pairs, the text doesn't show up. Below is my code taken from my rspec/capybara testing:

```
given(:dog_owner_one) { Dog.create(:first_name => 'Carmen', :last_name => 'Dent',
    :email => 'cdent@someemail.com', :dog_name => 'Shelby') }
given(:dog_owner_two) { Dog.create(:first_name => 'David', :last_name => 'Rubio',
    :email => 'dnr@someemail.com', :dog_name => 'Chronus') }

 scenario 'create a valid dog' do
  valid_dog = Dog.count
  dog_name = "Rover"
  first_name = "Daniel"
  visit new_dog_path
  fill_in 'First Name', with: first_name
  fill_in 'Last Name', with: 'Rubio'
  fill_in 'Email Address', with: 'www.drubio1989@gmail.com'
  fill_in 'Dog Name', with: dog_name
  click_button 'Register Dog'
  expect(page).to have_content('Dog Registered')
  expect(Dog.count).to eql(valid_dog + 1)
  expect(page).to have_content(first_name)
  expect(page).to have_content(dog_name)
  expect(page).to have_content(dog_owner_one.first_name)
  expect(page).to have_content(dog_owner_one.dog_name)
  expect(page).to have_content(dog_owner_two.first_name)
  expect(page).to have_content(dog_owner_one.dog_name)
end
```

There's something wrong with my syntax. I'm pretty new to rails and capybara but I'm pretty sure this should have worked. I've tried Dog.make but the rspec error tells me that there is an undefined method 'make' so that didn't work. I've also tried to fix the expect syntax like this:

```
  expect(page).to have_content(dog_owner_one[first_name])
  expect(page).to have_content(dog_owner_one[dog_name])
  expect(page).to have_content(dog_owner_two[first_name])
  expect(page).to have_content(dog_owner_one[dog_name])
```

This passes, but it doesn't show up on my web page. Which is bad..... I've tried this:

```
expect(page).to have_content(dog_owner_one.first_name)
  expect(page).to have_content(dog_owner_one.dog_name)
  expect(page).to have_content(dog_owner_two.first_name)
  expect(page).to have_content(dog_owner_one.dog_name)
```

What could be the problem? I don't know what else to try.

I don't know if this would be helpful but here is my code for my index.html.erb file:

```
<h1> List of Registered Dogs </h1>

<% if @dog.present? %>
  <ul>
  <% @dog.each do |dog| %>
    <li><%= "#{dog.first_name + ':' + ' ' + dog.dog_name}" %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that it has something to do with your `given` blocks.
Try:

```
background do
  dog_owner_one = Dog.create(:first_name => 'Carmen', :last_name => 'Dent', :email => 'cdent@someemail.com', :dog_name => 'Shelby')
  dog_owner_two = Dog.create(:first_name => 'David', :last_name => 'Rubio', :email => 'dnr@someemail.com', :dog_name => 'Chronus')
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I tried this and it doesn't work unless I exclude the background/do/end block. I don't understand why though.